# Turn URLs into links when showing the latest tweet from a Twitter account with preg_replace

Tags: php, twitter, preg-replace, tweets

I have cobbled together the code block below to help me show the latest tweet on my website from my Twitter account. However, it's not quite working right, can you help me debug this last little bit. I am looking for the PHP to turn it to HTML with link tags wrapped around the Twitter usernames and links which it is doing using `preg_replace`.

If you test this script you'll see there is a problem with when it renders out standard links in tweets it puts the closing <a> tag in too early after `a`. I'm sure this is relatively simple to fix and probably about escaping characters or something.

My main codeblock:

```
    <?php
        /** Script to pull in the latest tweet */
        $username='benpaton';
        $format = 'json';
        $tweet = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/{$username}.{$format}"));
        $latestTweet = htmlentities($tweet[0]->text, ENT_QUOTES);
        $latestTweet = preg_replace('/http:\/\/([[a-z0-9_\.\-\+\&\!\#\~\,]+)/i', '<a href="http://$1" target="_blank">http://$1</a>', $latestTweet);
        $latestTweet = preg_replace('/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $latestTweet);
        echo $latestTweet;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thought: could you just split the tweet by spaces and convert to URL any of those segments that start with "http://"? It's much, much cheaper than running a regular expression, simpler, and I think it would work just as well for this use case.

Comment: This sounds feasable. I'm not sure how to do this though also the @usernames don't start with "http://"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your regular expression to:

```
$latestTweet = preg_replace('/http:\/\/([a-z0-9_\.\-\+\&\!\#\~\/\,]+)/i', '<a href="http://$1" target="_blank">http://$1</a>', $latestTweet);
```

This worked for me.

**Full code**

```
<?php
    /** Script to pull in the latest tweet */
    $username='benpaton';
    $format = 'json';
    $tweet = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/{$username}.{$format}"));
    $latestTweet = htmlentities($tweet[0]->text, ENT_QUOTES);
    $latestTweet = preg_replace('/http:\/\/([a-z0-9_\.\-\+\&\!\#\~\/\,]+)/i', '<a href="http://$1" target="_blank">http://$1</a>', $latestTweet);
    $latestTweet = preg_replace('/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $latestTweet);
    echo $latestTweet;
?>
```

Comment: When I use your preg_replace line inserted into my code block $latestTweet doesn't get echoed out at all for me which is weird.

Comment: it posts something like this @bandq @Yellowkim check this out: <-- http://paper.li/bandq -->(as full link)

Comment: Thank you yes that works, I got it working on my site too now. Not sure why it was playing up for a second. Very much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
/** Script to pull in the latest tweet */
$username='benpaton';
$format = 'json';
$tweet = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/{$username}.{$format}"));
$latestTweet = htmlentities($tweet[0]->text, ENT_QUOTES);
$latestTweet = preg_replace('%http://[a-z0-9_.+&!#~/,\-]+%', '<a href="http://$1" target="_blank">http://$1</a>', $latestTweet);
$latestTweet = preg_replace('/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>', $latestTweet);
echo $latestTweet;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the code is buggy or incomplete! What you want to do is something like:

```
$tweets[$i]['text_html'] = htmlspecialchars($tweet['text']);
$tweets[$i]['text_html'] = preg_replace('%(http://([a-z0-9_.+&!#~/,\-]+))%i','<a href="http://$2">$1</a>',$tweets[$i]['text_html']);
$tweets[$i]['text_html'] = preg_replace('/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i','<a href="http://twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>',$tweets[$i]['text_html']);
```